# Java-Json Parsing issue-Escaping the XML characters

Tags: java, android, xml, json

I'm unable to escape the XML charecters in the Json response.
Here is the JSON response

```
{"projectId":14,"modificationDate":1379677731000,"projectJsonData":"{&quot;playerConfig&quot;:{&quot;autoPlay&quot;:true,&quot;initVolume&quot;:&quot;50&quot;,&quot;initFullScreen&quot;:false,&quot;size&quot;:&quot;container&quot;,&quot;splashPoster&quot;:&quot;defailt.png&quot;,&quot;projectId&quot;:123456},&quot;formList&quot;:[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;form&quot;,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;form-image&quot;,&quot;position&quot;:&quot;inscreen&quot;,&quot;transition&quot;:&quot;comealive-fade&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:50,&quot;zindex&quot;:998,&quot;start&quot;:12.9125390745513,&quot;end&quot;:16.90343280291607,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;complexForm1&quot;,&quot;layout&quot;:&quot;formTemplate&quot;,&quot;imgSrc&quot;:&quot;images/birds.jpg&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Gannets usually found in Australia..&quot;,&quot;desc&quot;:&quot;The birds that you see in this video are Gannets usually found in Australia and New Zealand. Diving birds are birds which plunge into water to catch fish or other food. They may enter the water from flight, as does the brown pelican or they may dive from the surface of the water. More than likely they evolved from birds already adapted for swimming that were equipped with such adaptations as lobed or webbed feet for propulsion.&quot;,&quot;button&quot;:[{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Gannets&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gannet&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;link&quot;},{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Aussie Gannet&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australasian_Gannet&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;link&quot;},{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Photography&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;http://aloneatseaphotography.com.au/8950&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;link&quot;}],&quot;displayType&quot;:&quot;non-intrusive&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;internal-seek&quot;},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;form&quot;,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;form-video&quot;,&quot;start&quot;:26.9125390745513,&quot;end&quot;:35.90343280291607,&quot;target&quot;:&quot;video-container&quot;,&quot;position&quot;:&quot;custom&quot;,&quot;transition&quot;:&quot;comealive-fade&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;complexForm2&quot;,&quot;layout&quot;:&quot;formTemplate&quot;,&quot;videoSrc&quot;:[{&quot;src&quot;:&quot;videos/ocean.mp4&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;video/mp4&quot;,&quot;codecs&quot;:&quot;vp8,vorbis&quot;},{&quot;src&quot;:&quot;videos/ocean.webm&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;video/webm&quot;,&quot;codecs&quot;:&quot;vp8,vorbis&quot;}],&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Slow Motion&quot;,&quot;desc&quot;:&quot;Gannets in super slow-mo&quot;,&quot;button&quot;:[],&quot;displayType&quot;:&quot;non-intrusive&quot;,&quot;tags&quot;:&quot;Gannets&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;internal-seek&quot;},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;form&quot;,&quot;subType&quot;:&quot;form-custom&quot;,&quot;start&quot;:4,&quot;end&quot;:10,&quot;target&quot;:&quot;video-container&quot;,&quot;position&quot;:&quot;custom&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;complexForm3&quot;,&quot;layout&quot;:&quot;custom&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Gannets&quot;,&quot;content&quot;:&quot;%3Cimg%20style%3D%22position%3Aabsolute%3Bright%3A10%25%3Btop%3A20px%22%20width%3D%22150%22%20height%3D%22150%22%20src%3D%22images%2Fbirds.jpg%22%20%2F%3E&quot;,&quot;displayType&quot;:&quot;intrusive-parallel&quot;,&quot;desc&quot;:&quot;Gannets&quot;,&quot;tags&quot;:&quot;Gannets&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;internal-seek&quot;,&quot;animation&quot;:&quot;slideIn-600-easeOutBounce&quot;}
```

I have given partial Json response due to size limitation here.
I have used the following to parse the response

`JSONObject jsonProjectDataObject = new JSONObject(
StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(videoGetResponse.get("projectJsonData").toString()));`

Now I get the exception as

`org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after &quot at character 7 of {&quot;playerConfig&quot;:{&quot;autoPlay&quot;:true,&quot;initVolume&quot;:&quot;50&quot;,&quot;initFullScreen&quot`

Comment: Its invalid json, what is the question?

Comment: its valid until the & symbol. check: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: It is completely a valid JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is not XML.  Using XML entities is not the appropriate way to escape JSON.

Double quote escaped using XML entities: `&quot;`

Double quote escaped using JSON : `\"`

Comment: Didn't quite get you !

Comment: @user2813821 do not escape a json string using XML escaping method "StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml"

Answer (score 0):

Paste your output [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/) it says its invalid json. Before parsing json check this link